# How to run jQuery only on a specific option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        //Range
        var val = $('#slider').val();
        output = $('#output');
        output.html(val);
    
        $('#slider').on('change', function() {
          output.html(this.value);
        });
    
        $('#Main').change(function() {
          if (this.value == "a") {
            $('#slider').prop({
              'min': 0,
              'max': 1
            });
          }
          if (this.value == "b") {
            $('#slider').prop({
              'min': 0,
              'max': 20
            });
          }
          if (this.value == "c") {
         var style = $('#slider').attr('style'),
            textbox = $(document.createElement('textarea')).attr('style',style);
         $('#slider').replaceWith(textbox);
          }       
          $('#slider').val(0);
          output.html('0');
        });
      }
    </script>
      <body>
        <form>
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Title</legend>
            <p>
              <label>
                Select modifier:
              </label>
              <select id="Main" onchange="changeRange('10', '80')">
               <option value="default">select an option</option>
                <option value="a">Option A</option>
                <option value="b">Option B</option>            
                <option value="c">Option C</option>                               
              </select>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="range">Select amount:</label>
              <input type="range" min="0" max="9000" id="slider" value="0" name="range"> <span id="output"></span>
            </p>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </body>
```

The code for option A and B is working fine at the moment. I would like option C to display a textbox instead of a slider, which is also working fine. However, when option B is selected after option C, the textbox still remains. I only want the textbox to appear for option C. I have tried adding this to `if (this.value == "c") {`

```
else {
            var dstyle = $('#slider').attr('dstyle'),
            range = $(document.createElement('range')).attr('dstyle',style);
            $('#slider').replaceWith(range);
        }
```

However, that did not work. Please help me resolve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Please note that the code snippet shows some errors, however the code is still functioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the working solution below. I have used `switch` instead of `if` and created a `textarea` in HTML. After that just show/hide `textarea` and `slider`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //Range
  var val = $('#slider').val();
  output = $('#output');
  output.html(val);

  $('#slider').on('change', function() {
    output.html(this.value);
  });

  function showSlider() {
    $('#slider').show();
    $('#textInput').hide();
  }

  function showTextInput() {
    $('#slider').hide();
    $('#textInput').show();
  }

  $('#Main').change(function() {
    switch (this.value) {
      case 'a':
        $('#slider').prop({
          'min': 0,
          'max': 1
        });
        showSlider();
        break;
      case 'b':
        $('#slider').prop({
          'min': 0,
          'max': 20
        });
        showSlider();
        break;
      case 'c':
        showTextInput();
        break;
      default:
    }
    $('#slider').val(0);
    output.html('0');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Title</legend>
    <p>
      <label>
                Select modifier:
              </label>
      <select id="Main">
               <option value="default">select an option</option>
                <option value="a">Option A</option>
                <option value="b">Option B</option>            
                <option value="c">Option C</option>                               
              </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="range">Select amount:</label>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="9000" id="slider" value="0" name="range">
      <textarea id="textInput" style="display:none"></textarea>
      <span id="output"></span>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new element every time you select option c, just hide and unhide it.
Here's a pure javascript code I created:

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var slider = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var val = select.value;
  console.log(val)
  if (val == 'a') {
    slider.style.display = "initial";
    textarea.style.display = "none";
    slider.setAttribute('min', 0);
    slider.setAttribute('max', 1);
  }
  else if (val == 'b') {
    slider.style.display = "initial";
    textarea.style.display = "none";
    slider.setAttribute('min', 0);
    slider.setAttribute('max', 20);
  }
  else if (val == 'c') {
    slider.style.display = "none";
    textarea.style.display = "initial";
    slider.setAttribute('min', 0);
    slider.setAttribute('max', 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <select>
      <option value="a">Option A</option>
      <option value="b">Option B</option>            
      <option value="c">Option C</option> 
    </select>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1">
    <textarea style="display:none"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide and show the elements based on the selected option values. See example below

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var val = $('#slider').val();
  output = $('#output');
  output.html(val);

  $('#slider').on('change', function() {
    output.html(this.value);
  });

  $('#Main').change(function() {
  console.log(this.value);
    if (this.value == "a") {
      $('#slider').show();
      $("#amntxt").hide();
      $('#slider').prop({
        'min': 0,
        'max': 1
      });
    }
    if (this.value == "b") {
      $('#slider').show();
      $("#amntxt").hide();
      $('#slider').prop({
        'min': 0,
        'max': 20
      });
    }
    if (this.value == "c") {
      $("#amntxt").show();
      $('#slider').hide();
    }
    $('#slider').val(0);
    output.html('0');
  });
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Title</legend>
    <p>
      <label>
                Select modifier:
              </label>
      <select id="Main">
               <option value="default">select an option</option>
                <option value="a">Option A</option>
                <option value="b">Option B</option>            
                <option value="c">Option C</option>                               
              </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="range">Select amount:</label>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="9000" id="slider" value="0" name="range"> 
      <textarea id="amntxt" style="display:none;"></textarea>
      <span id="output"></span>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```